# How to select column index from table and set values dynamically using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a doubt regarding how to find row/column index from a table using angular.js .I am explaining one example below.

suppose i have a table with some data which is given below.

```
sl no    name     roll-no1   roll-no2     roll-no3  action

1         jack     3           5             7       Change

2         Rahul     4          7              9      change
```

and the code of this table given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="table">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<script src="angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="appController">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th> Name</th>
<th>roll-no1</th>
<th>roll-no2</th>
<th>roll-no3 </th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="role in userHomeRoleValue">
<td class="role">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="role">{{role.user_name}}</td>
<td class="role">{{role.roll1}}</td>
<td class="role">{{role.roll2}}</td>
<td class="role">{{role.roll3}}</td>
<td><button type="button" id="btn" ng-click="changeRow($index)">Change</button></td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In controller file i have the below line of code.

```
   var app=angular.module('table',[]);
app.controller('appController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.userHomeRoleValue=[
{'user_name':"jack",'roll1':3,'roll2':5,'roll3':7},
{'user_name':"rahul",'roll1':4,'roll2':7,'roll3':9}
]
console.log('user',$scope.userHomeRoleValue);
$scope.changeRow = function(index) {
var rowData = $scope.userHomeRoleValue[index];
// Do whatever you want to change here because the rowData is the row the user clicked the change button on!
}
});
app.directive("test", function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                angular.forEach(elem.siblings(), function(value, key) {
                    if (value.hasClass('role')) {
                        angular.element(value).text(elem.text());
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

These table values will display using  `ng-repeat` and values will assign dynamically in controller file.In action column lets say `change` is the button name.Here i need when user will click on change button of first row,the index of value under roll-no1 will be fetch and that value will update with roll-no2 and roll-no3 values of the same row.Lets assume all table headers are also set dynamically.Please help me.

Comment: Can you post your ng-repeat code?

Comment: ok,let me to post the code part.

Comment: @ShijuKBabu : Now you can check the post.

Comment: How about to put ng-click on row and pass role object, so u can do what ever you want in function ... ng-click="change(role)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `ng-click="changeRow($index)"` on change buttons.
In your controller add the code below:

```
$scope.changeRow = function(index) {
var rowData = $scope.userHomeRoleValue[index];
// Do whatever you want to change here because the rowData is the row the user clicked the change button on!
}
```

**UPDATE**
For the change you wanted in the comments, make a directive and set the directive to all "rol-no" elements and add a class for tracking them.

```
<td class="role">{{role.roll1}}</td>
<td class="role">{{role.roll2}}</td>
<td class="role">{{role.roll3}}</td>

app.directive("test", function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                angular.forEach(elem.siblings(), function(value, key) {
                    if (angular.element(value).hasClass('role')) {
                        angular.element(value).text(elem.text());
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Farzad : Ok but how to bind the same data in next 2 cells.

Comment: @subhra Could you please be more specific? What do you mean by binding?

Comment: @ Farzad : Did you properly go through my post ? Let me to explain again.Suppose i clicked on 1st row change button when i will click the the value at roll-no1(`i.e-3`) will fetch and it will set to roll-no2 and roll-no3 of the same row.

Comment: So you want when user clicks on row1 rol-no1, it's value be set on the same row on rol-no2 and rol-no3 also?

Comment: @ Farzad : Did you find any solution.

Comment: I added the update you wanted . check the code under UPDATE in the solution.

Comment: @ Farzad : I added your code but its not working as per requirement.I am updating my code please check again.

Comment: @ Farzad : I added my updated code please check where i did mistake.

Comment: Remove the role class from two first td elements.                                   <td class="role">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="role">{{role.user_name}}</td> ans add test attribute to the last 3 td elements                                                                                 <td test class="role">{{role.roll1}}</td>
<td test class="role">{{role.roll2}}</td>
<td test class="role">{{role.roll3}}</td>

Comment: @ Farzad : i did as per you but after click on change button the value did not set in other two roll-n02 and roll-no3 .

Comment: @ Faraz : But one thing after click on value `3` this error `Uncaught TypeError: elem.siblings is not a function` is coming.

Comment: Please make a fiddle or plunker, add all your html and js codes so i could see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I can give you my online link `oditek.in/table`.Open this link.